# Spring form select a enum from a object

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I'm making a form to edit users, each user has multiples roles (based on Spring Security). The problem is that the select option is not preselected with the correspondents roles of the users.

User

```
public class User implements UserDetails {
   ...
   private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>(0);
   ...
}
```

Roles

```
public class UserRole implements GrantedAuthority {
   ...
   private Role role; //enum {ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER,...}
   ...
}
```

Form

```
<form:fomr commandName="user">
   <form:input path="username" />
   ...
   <form:select multiple="true" path="userRoles" itemValue="role">
      <form:options items="${roles}"/>
   </form:select>
   ...
</form:form>
```

I'm sure that the problem come from "userRoles", it is a `Set` of a different type that "roles". There is an another way to make the form?

PS:`items=${roles} == Roles.values()`

**edited:**

```
User user = getUserById(id);
model.addAttribute("newUser", user);

@Transactional
public User getUserById(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    User user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
    if (user != null) {
        user.getUserRoles().size();
    }
    return user;
}
```

Comment: How did you set the roles parameter in controller, could you share it?

Comment: edited @SemihEker. the data comming from the database is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this "solution", but I was looking for some thing that spring do automatically

```
        ...
        <form:select multiple="true" path="userRoles" itemValue="role">
            <c:forEach items="${roles}" var="role">
                <c:set var="selected" value="false" />
                <c:forEach items="${newUser.userRoles}" var="userRole">
                    <c:if test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(userRole, role)}">
                        <form:option value="${role}" selected="true"/>
                        <c:set var="selected" value="true" />
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
                <c:if test="${selected eq false}">
                    <form:option value="${role}"/>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Role enum have the following code;

```
public enum Role {
    private static Map<Integer, String> idNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    static {
        for(Role role:Role.values()) {
             idNameMap.put(role.ordinal(), role.name());
        }
    }

    public static Map<Integer, String> getIdNameMap() {
        return idNameMap;
    }
}
```

Now in your controller code instead of doing this

```
items=${roles} == Roles.values()
```

Do

```
items=${roles} == Roles.getIdNameMap()
```

This should ideally fix your issue.

Comment: with this solution change the values to an index, but doesn't too